# regex - Notepad++ search and replace losing lines

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I’m very new to regex, and I’m trying to use Notepad++ to clean up some CSV files. I am running version 7.8.2 (64-bit), as my files are too large for the 32-bit version to open.

Within the data, most of the fields are standardized and automatically generated by the system. There are exactly 30 fields in each row. There is one field where user can enter comments, however, and in a few cases, users have entered a line break within this field. When this happens, Notepad++ creates a new line for this data.

For example, the third line below should be a continuation of the second line *(edited from condensed example in the original post)*:

```
"39901","0002286898","88","ACTUALS","TO RECORD ACCRUED LIABILITIES FOR GOODS OR SERVICES RECEIVED AT JUNE 30 2016 PER ATTACHED SCHEDULE. FOR 39901, IU journal  2297455 CONTACT: [NAME PHONE NUMBER] / [NAME PHONE NUMBER]","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","191313.130","07/28/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities","" 
"39901","0002290128","7","ACTUALS","To record accrued liabilities for goods or services received at June 30, 2016 per the attached schedule.  
Contact [NAME PHONE NUMBER EMAIL] or [NAME PHONE NUMBER EMAIL]","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","2556242.170","07/31/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities","" 
"39901","0002291224","37","ACTUALS","TO RECORD ACCRUED LIABILITIES FOR GOODS OR SERVICES RECEIVED AT JUNE 30 PER THE ATTACHED SCHEDULE.  FOR 34530, CONTACT: [NAME PHONE NUMBER EMAIL]","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","3010262.140","07/27/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities","" 
"39901","0002291259","2","ACTUALS","TO RECORD ACCRUED LIABILITIES FOR GOODS OR SERVICES RECEIVED AT JUNE 30 PER THE ATTACHED SCHEDULE.  FOR 34571, CONTACT: [NAME PHONE NUMBER] / [NAME PHONE NUMBER]","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","38140.260","07/27/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities","" 
"39901","0002291336","12","ACTUALS","TO RECORD ACCRUED LIABILITIES FOR GOODS OR SERVICES RECEIVED AT JUNE 30  PER ATTACHED SCHEDULE. FOR 345.20","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","2768000.000","08/01/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities",""
```

I am trying to remove the extra line feed in the second row so that the data instead looks like:

```
"39901","0002286898","88","ACTUALS","TO RECORD ACCRUED LIABILITIES FOR GOODS OR SERVICES RECEIVED AT JUNE 30 2016 PER ATTACHED SCHEDULE. FOR 39901, IU journal  2297455 CONTACT: [NAME PHONE NUMBER] / [NAME PHONE NUMBER]","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","191313.130","07/28/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities","" 
"39901","0002290128","7","ACTUALS","To record accrued liabilities for goods or services received at June 30, 2016 per the attached schedule.  Contact [NAME PHONE NUMBER EMAIL] or [NAME PHONE NUMBER EMAIL]","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","2556242.170","07/31/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities","" 
"39901","0002291224","37","ACTUALS","TO RECORD ACCRUED LIABILITIES FOR GOODS OR SERVICES RECEIVED AT JUNE 30 PER THE ATTACHED SCHEDULE.  FOR 34530, CONTACT: [NAME PHONE NUMBER EMAIL]","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","3010262.140","07/27/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities","" 
"39901","0002291259","2","ACTUALS","TO RECORD ACCRUED LIABILITIES FOR GOODS OR SERVICES RECEIVED AT JUNE 30 PER THE ATTACHED SCHEDULE.  FOR 34571, CONTACT: [NAME PHONE NUMBER] / [NAME PHONE NUMBER]","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","38140.260","07/27/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities","" 
"39901","0002291336","12","ACTUALS","TO RECORD ACCRUED LIABILITIES FOR GOODS OR SERVICES RECEIVED AT JUNE 30  PER ATTACHED SCHEDULE. FOR 345.20","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","2768000.000","08/01/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities",""
```

There is no carriage return, only a line feed, so searching for `\n` also flags all of the line feeds that should legitimately end the line.

In this case, the data is structured so that the last column is always blank `("")`. As such, I have tried to search for lines where the end is not blank – the line ends with a letter, number, period, space, etc. My plan is to replace these instances with a uniquely odd word, and then do a second, expanded search and replace to get rid of the new expression and the line feed.

Although unwieldy, I’ve been doing it in steps:

- `\d{1}$` to find lines where the last character is a number;
- `\w{1}$` to find lines where the last character is a letter;
- `\s{1}$` to find lines where the last character is whitespace; and
- `\.$` to find lines that end with a period.

I will then do a last search to find any stragglers that don’t start with `39901`.

I run these searches as a regular search, and then replace with `REPLACEHERE999_`, which I assume no one else has entered into the data. I understand that this will remove and replace the last character in the line – the final number, letter, space, etc. – but I can live with that. After these replacements have been made, I plan to then do a second, expanded search to swap out `REPLACEHERE999_\n` with a space, getting rid of both `REPLACEHERE999_` and the line feed.

When I do the first searches, they make a reasonable number of substitutions based on the number of errors I initially got in Power Query – 377 for `\d{1}$`, for example. Once I make these replacements, however, the number of lines drops significantly. Originally, I had 3,919,186 lines, but after the first search and replace – `\d{1}$` – I only had 1,543,818 lines, less than half of what I started with. When I work through the first few replacements one at a time, I don’t lose lines, but when I use “Replace All,” they disappear.

Again, I just started with regex/Notepad++, so I may be missing some basic thing. But if I am only making a limited number of replacements, why are so many of my lines vanishing?

Comments and suggestions on my searches or thinking are welcome, but the disappearing lines are the crucial issue here.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `(?:“[^”\n]+|\G(?!\A))\K\n` work for you?

Comment: Does your data really have Unicode quotes?

Comment: @ctwheels I just tried it, but it only returned the very last line, which is blank.

Comment: @tripleee Yes. I mean, they're all straight in the actual data, but yes, that's how it comes out of our system.

Comment: @Capo not sure what you mean, just tested it in Notepad++ and it was successful. I copied your input and duplicated it twice (for two instances), clicked "Replace All" and it says "Replace All: 2 occurrences were replaced"

Comment: @ctwheels Your suggestion is definitely more complicated than I can follow, so I'm not sure exactly what it's doing, but my example is pretty condensed. My actual data has 30 columns, with the issues in column 5. Would that affect your suggestion?

Comment: @Capo it would not - I can convert this to an answer and explain it; but I prefer to know that it works for your cases first.

Comment: This may involve negations of regexes

Comment: @Capo Does all of the new data lines begin with “39901”? If not, are they continuation lines?

Comment: @ctwheels Oddly enough, it works on the example data I provided, but not in my actual dataset. Let me edit my original post to provide a fuller sample.

Comment: Great! Also consider all of the other odd test cases.

Comment: @ctwheels I've added a snippet of the full data at the end of the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Does the answer have to be in one regex?

Comment: @Capo can you clarify if the characters are `"` or `“”`? You have both in two different samples.

Comment: @ctwheels Sorry, they are all straight (unless someone has curly quotes within the user-entered field). I've just edited the original post to make it consistent.

Comment: How much columns does each row contain?

Comment: "(\w|\s|[.,:/\[\]])*",

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica There are 30 columns in each row.

Comment: @Capo the problem you're going to have with almost any answer here is that balancing `"` is very difficult in regex. Some of the hacks may work like [Toto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59649328/3600709). Are escaped `\"` possible in your inputs?

Comment: @Capo Done. This assumes all of your rows consists of exactly 30 columns. Are you okay if my solution has two steps?

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica I don't care if it has 10 steps, as long as it works! :)

Comment: @Capo. Give it a try. My solution has 2 steps; first step is to remove newline.. Click the checkmark if the solutions work.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!“)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak
(?!“)       # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't “ after
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Might not work for non-matching lines beginning with quotes

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica: I assume that all complete lines begin with opening quote `“`

Comment: "I will then do a last search to find any stragglers that don’t start with 39901."

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica: Sorry, I don't get you. My solution doesn't need line to begin with 39901

Comment: Your solution fails for continuation lines which begin with quotes. [which does not have 30 entries]

Answer (score 0):

Assume each row contains exactly *30* columns, and each column can contain any character other than the double quotes:

Turning on *extended mode* and *regular expression search* and wraparound,
you can do it in two steps:

1. Remove all the newlines. [[Step 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urRBi.png)
2. Use this regex, `(("[^"]*",){29}("[^"]*")\s?)`
   and replace it with `$1\n` from the "Replace With :" field.  [[Step 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3mKh.png) [[Results]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpZCk.png)

Explanation:

- Each field is of form `"[^"]*"`. In your case, there are 30 rows, the first 29 are followed by commas.
- In my regex, the allowed characters are all the characters *but* the double quotes.
- Let's express `[^"]` as *`\x`*. Then each field is of form *`"\x*"`* Then we have regex *`("\x*",{29}"\x*")`* repeated several times. We add a new line for each segment of that form.
- The `\s?` can deal with the residual space after every *30* entries.

**NOTE:** The links use the previous, less inclusive regex.

Comment: I can't make it work, please, show capture screens.

Comment: I corrected my solution. To remove all the newlines, find `\r`, then replace with empty.

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica This looks like it will work for me, although it's a large file and it's been replacing new lines for pushing 10 minutes now. Also, when I get to step 2, will I need to add a hyphen `\-` to the list of characters to pick up negative numbers?

Comment: You can do that. But please modify both `[.,:/\[\]]` in regex.

Comment: @Capo: Have you tried [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59649328/372239)? Just change curly quotes with straight ones, I'll update my answer if it's correct for you.

Comment: I ran your solution. Your solution failed for cases where a new line beginning with quotes are continuations of the previous line. It worked well in my algorithm.

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica Yes, it finished up getting rid of the new lines and put everything one one line. It just finished up the replace all on step 2 a minute ago, but said that 0 occurrences were replaced. My guess is that there are some other wonky characters buried in there somewhere, but out of 4M rows of data, I don't know that I'd ever be able to identify them all.

Comment: @Capo I made another revision to my regex. Now all of `[.,:/\[\]\-]` have been replaced with `[^"]`, all characters are permitted inside fields except for quotation marks. If some of your fields themselves has quotation marks, let me know.

Comment: @Capo Is it okay if you can give a link to your dataset so I can take a look? [such as on Github, etc.]

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica It's possible, depending on how Accounting was feeling that day. Let me try the revision and I'll see how it goes.

Comment: @Capo Great. If it still doesn't work, can you please post your dataset [or a part of it] to my email? I am mulliganaceous@gmail.com [can be found on my profile]

Comment: @Capo The file isn't correct. It should be a csv file, not a xlsx file. Is the regex still working?

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica Yes, it's still running your revision to include all characters.

Comment: @Capo Can you directly send the csv file to my email [mulliganaceous@gmail.com] as an attachment?

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica I'll try it again and send you another link. Might be a few minutes, though.

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica Not sure where my last comment got off to. The file is too large to send directly through email, so I reuploaded and sent a new link. It's says it's a CSV file and downloads as a CSV on my end, so let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Okay. sorry about that. It is too large. Can you create a copy of that csv file and remove most of the rows until it is strictly less than 40 MB? and then send it to me?

Comment: @Capo

I finished running the abridged CSV on my end using the most recent answer. 148622 occurrences were replaced.

Comment: @Capo Is your replacement step still running?

Comment: @MulliganᛜReinstatingMonica It looked like it was stuck beyond salvaging, so I closed it. I can try again or with a different regex.

Comment: Sure. I know you have a very large CSV file that took forever to run. For my abridged version, it yielded the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

### Hacks

Other hack answers exist and they're all viable, just depends on how you want/need to go about it. I'm tackling hacks based on the end of the line rather than the start of the next line as other answers address (e.g. `\R(?!")` as proposed by [Toto in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59649328/3600709)).

#### Reset hack: `\K`

This particular method is a hack based on the current line's ending. Most other hacks here take the next line into account instead.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/7ml7sf/1)

```
[^" ] *\K\R
```

Alternatively, you could use `([^" ] *)\R` replace with `$1`

This matches all lines that have any non-space/non-`"` character followed by any number of whitespace characters, then resets the match (previously matched characters are no longer part of the final match), then matches newline character.

#### Skip/Fail hack: `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`

Similar to previous, just using control verbs rather than reset token. Speed advantage over reset method.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/7ml7sf/2)

```
" *\R(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\R
```

This matches all lines that end in `"` (then followed by any number of spaces), then skips those lines with a forced failure. The alternation of `\R` matches newline combinations and in this case will only match where the first alternation doesn't.

Make sure you have ***Backward direction*** selected:

[image: Notepad++ settings image using regex defined above and backward direction enabled]

---

Other answers here tackle checking next line and they're all great answers, so I won't provide any in my answer.

---

### Balancing `"`

Unfortunately, matching balanced `"` is difficult in regex (not impossible, just not the best tool).

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/7ml7sf/5)

```
("((?<!\\)\\(?:\\{2})*"|[^"\n\r])*"|^[^"\r\n]*"),? *(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|"[^"\r\n]*\K\R+
```

This pattern matches `"` followed by any non-`"` character or escaped `\"`, and then the closing `"`; or it matches any character except `"` or newline characters, then `"`. It then optionally matches a combination of `,` and/or any number of spaces. We then skip/fail these matches because they're all balanced `"` or the ends of the unbalanced `"`. We then match all the unbalanced `"` (where `"` opens on one line, but doesn't close on the same line), match up to the newline character, reset the match and match the newline character. The result is any newline character that breaks the balance of `"`.

This regex pattern is correct, but, unfortunately, this only works for matching or for the **Replace** function in Notepad++. I don't know why, but **Replace All** replaces 2 instances rather than 1.

Using **Replace** button (yields the message *Replace: 1 occurrence was replaced. **The next occurrence found***):

[image: Using the Replace function with the pattern above in Notepad++]

After clicking on **Replace** again, nothing happens:

[image: Second click on Replace fails although the message says it found the next occurrence]

As mentioned, **Replace All** replaces too much:

[image: Replace All matching two locations instead of one]

My suggestion? Use one of the hack patterns I describe above or one from another answer if you can. It's quick and dirty, but works. If you need to check balanced `"`, use the last pattern, just know that you'll have to click **Replace** for every single match.

P.S. I haven't been able to identify the Replace vs Replace All issue, but I'm on version 7.8.1 of Notepad++; this may be a version(s)-specific issue.

---

Result for each of the patterns described above in Notepad++:

```
"39901","0002286898","88","ACTUALS","TO RECORD ACCRUED LIABILITIES FOR GOODS OR SERVICES RECEIVED AT JUNE 30 2016 PER ATTACHED SCHEDULE. FOR 39901, IU journal  2297455 CONTACT: [NAME PHONE NUMBER] / [NAME PHONE NUMBER]","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","191313.130","07/28/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities","" 
"39901","0002290128","7","ACTUALS","To record accrued liabilities for goods or services received at June 30, 2016 per the attached schedule.  Contact [NAME PHONE NUMBER EMAIL] or [NAME PHONE NUMBER EMAIL]","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","2556242.170","07/31/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities","" 
"39901","0002291224","37","ACTUALS","TO RECORD ACCRUED LIABILITIES FOR GOODS OR SERVICES RECEIVED AT JUNE 30 PER THE ATTACHED SCHEDULE.  FOR 34530, CONTACT: [NAME PHONE NUMBER EMAIL]","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","3010262.140","07/27/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities","" 
"39901","0002291259","2","ACTUALS","TO RECORD ACCRUED LIABILITIES FOR GOODS OR SERVICES RECEIVED AT JUNE 30 PER THE ATTACHED SCHEDULE.  FOR 34571, CONTACT: [NAME PHONE NUMBER] / [NAME PHONE NUMBER]","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","38140.260","07/27/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities","" 
"39901","0002291336","12","ACTUALS","TO RECORD ACCRUED LIABILITIES FOR GOODS OR SERVICES RECEIVED AT JUNE 30  PER ATTACHED SCHEDULE. FOR 345.20","LA","34000000","Accrued Liabilities","","11000","","","","","","","","","","","","","2017","1","2768000.000","08/01/2016","07/01/2016","","Accrued Liabilities",""
```

Comment: The LF part is now obsolete for this question. The asker already gave more clarifications on the intended form of the output.